# Whats the difference between these two comparison statements?

Tags: c#, .net

Whats the difference between these two comparison statments?

```
var result = EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(@this, null);
var result = @this == null;
```

Obviously the aim is to test whether the object '@this' isnull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

operator `==` calls `ReferenceEquals` on comparing objects, so compare that objects are pointing to the same memory location.

`Equals`, instead,  is a just virtual method, so **can** behave *differently* for different types, as it can be overriden.

For example, for CLR `string` Equals compares *content* of a `string` and not a *reference*, even if `string` is a reference type.

Comment: `==` *might* call `ReferenceEquals`.  It depends on the type of `@this`.  It could be overwritten.

Answer (score 7):

Well it depends on the type of `@this`. If it doesn't have an overload of `==`, the second line will just perform a direct reference comparison, whereas the first line will call an *overridden* `Equals` method or an implementation of `IEquatable.Equals`.

Any *sensible* implementation will give the same result for both comparisons.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it, but why can't you do this @this == default(T)?

Comment: @user1437135: There are limits around what you can compare with in generic methods. I can't remember the details off-hand (and I don't have the spec with me) but I believe you can *only* compare against `null`, unless you've constrained `T` to be a reference type. A comparison against `null` will always fail for any non-nullable value type.

Answer (score 2):

The first statement calls the [Equals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx) method between objects to see if their values are equal, assuming it has been overriden and implemented in the class `T`. The second statement compares the references instead, unless the `==` operator has been overridden like in the `String` class.